# El endpoint de mi Post no funciona

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario de contacto básico en React con un arhivo simple de php. Estoy usando también Axios para conectar el front con el back, pero no sé porqué me devuelve el estado `400` y un `Cannot POST /home/api/contact.php` pero no sé porqué. ¿Me podrán ayudar? No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal.

Este es mi componente ReactJS:

```
const SectionContact = ({sectionData, className}) => {
    
    const API_PATH = 'http://localhost:3000/yasmin-hiasche/api/contact.php';

    const sendMail = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let infoMail = {
            name: e.target.[0].value,
            email: e.target.[2].value,
            text: e.target.[4].value,
        };
        await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: `${API_PATH}`,
          headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
          data: infoMail
        })
    };
    
    return(
        <form className={`${classes.root} ${className}`} autoComplete="on" onSubmit={(e)=>sendMail(e)}>
            (...*inputs*...)
            <Button variant="outlined" type='submit' >Enviar</Button>            
            
        </form>
    )
}

export default SectionContact;
```

Y este es mi script de `php`:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

if ($_POST)
    {
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
    $subject = $_POST['infoMail.name'];
    $to = "yhbellydance@gmail.com";
    $from = $_POST['infoMail.email'];

    // data
    $msg = $_POST['infoMail.text'];

    // Headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers.= "From: <" . $from . ">";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

    // echo json_encode( $_POST )
    echojson_encode(array(
        "sent" => true
    ));
    }
  else
    {
    // tell the user about error
    echojson_encode(["sent" => false, "message" => "Something went wrong"]);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Haz un echo de `$_POST` ve como están los datos y si los recibes correctamente

Comment: .@cecilia hay que verificar esas rutas, en una dice `/yasmin-hiasche/api/contact.php` y en otra `/home/api/contact.php`, saludos

Comment: Ojo con el Content-Type se esta enviando como `application/json` mientras que el endpoint esta esperando un `text/html`